# What should be on 'this' on 'destroyed' hook for VueJS Component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a medium-sized app and notice a lot of memory increase when moving back and forth between components.

I put this on the component:

```
destroyed(){
    console.log(this
}
```

I was surprised to find a lot - if not all - the 'data' still there plus computed properties. I thought this was supposed to be clean at that point. What all should be expected to be destroyed by that point? Is this a cause for concern and a potential source of memory leaks?

Comment: Did you actually profile this or took a heap snapshot? You could also try and see what it looks like with a `nextTick` included to make sure your entire queue is flushed. Also if your reason for investigation is 'your app becoming sluggish', most of the time this is due to excessive dom manipulation in my experience.

Comment: @Stephan-v When using nextTick, it says "undefined".  I'm mainly concerned because the memory footprint keeps growing when moving between components. The application has a lot of large lists of data. I did figure out that having dev tools (with Vue dev tools) open, it significantly increases the memory usage.

It crashes when I try to take a heap on the big page I'm concerned about.

Comment: Are you displaying 500+ results on a page or something?

Comment: I'm now limiting it to 200 results at a time but I do have to have 2,000+ items in memory because the user is manually matching items between the lists.

I've manually unset all the big lists on beforeDestroy, which seems to help. The browser does still crash for some really big lists, even with the amount of rendered items on the page.